# Что означает поле класса, которое содержит объект данного класса?

Tags: ооп, любой-язык, singleton

Здравствуйте!

В коде часто встречается вот такая конструкция (в любом си-подобном языке).

```
class One {

One instanse; //Вот эта строчка не понятна

... //Здесь дальнейшая реализация
}
```

Такая строчка всегда встречается в [синглтоне](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) и (если я правильно понял) называется глобальной точкой доступа. Само поле класса, в котором заключен объект класса, наводит меня на мысль о рекурсии, совершенно не понятной.

**Вопросы:**

1. Что означает это поле?
2. Для чего используется это поле?
3. Как такое вообще возможно? Ведь класс - это суть штамп, а объект это отливка из штампа. Получается штамп содержит отливку? А каждый экземпляр уже содержит в себе экземпляр себя же?
4. Опционально - где и в какой книге (сайте) это понятно описано?

Comment: `static One instanse;`

Comment: иногда `private static One instance`.

Comment: @Igor у меня в java скомпилировался такой код: `public class SingleT {

    public int x, y;
    SingleT instance;

    SingleT(int x , int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleT st = new SingleT(5, 4);

    }
}`

Comment: @AndrewKachalin Та конструкция, как у вас (без `static`) может подойти, например, для построения цепи `прадед-дед-отец-сын-внук...`. Т.е. каждый объект содержит потомка своего же класса. Если со `static` - то это 99% синглтон. Про него можете сами почитать

Comment: @AndrewKachalin то, что он скомпилировался еще не значит что он верный. Потому что `instance` для **синглтона**  статический, чтоб был всегда доступ к ней через ClassName.instance

Comment: @АлексейШиманский конструкция абсолютно валидная. Единственное, что намекает на необходимость статики - это имя свойства, но только косвенно.

Comment: @rjhdby валидная, но не в контексте синглтона)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну так и вопрос в целом не за синглтон ;)

Comment: @rjhdby странно, увидев в вопросе `Такая строчка всегда встречается в синглтоне` и увидев метку [tag:синглтон] я почему-то подумал, что намекали именно на это)

Comment: Только это далеко не любой язык - C++ такое не допустит...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот в таком виде

```
class One {
    One instanse;
}
```

Это обычное свойство объекта. Никто не мешает объекту иметь свойство того же класса, к которому принадлежит и он сам. Например так можно реализовать стишок "За деревом дерево, и за деревом дерево, и за деревом дерево, вот и кончился лес (т.е. в последнем объекте это поле `null`)". В принципе так можно описать любую древовидную (рекурсивную) структуру. Вот вам узел бинарного дерева например:

```
class Node {
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

Если же мы видим такое

```
class One {
    private static One instanse;
}
```

То тут это поле является полем класса. Т.е. оно является общим для всех экземпляров класса. Обычно такие конструкции, вкупе с приватным конструктором и методом `getInstance()`:

```
private One(){...}

public static One getInstance() {  //самая простая реализация
    if(instance == null) instance = new One();
    return instance;
}
```

Обеспечивает, что будет создан один и только один экземпляр этого класса, который будет храниться в поле `instance` и порлучить который можно через `One.getInstance()`. Т.е. синглтон.

Comment: я вас правильно ли понял, что свойство объекта и поле класса не одно и тоже?  Я просто полагал, что объект характеризует: поведение (т.е. методы), сущность (т.е поля), состояние (т.е. значение полей).

Comment: @AndrewKachalin конечно не одно и то же. Прочитайте, что означает модификатор `static`

Comment: Чтобы могло быть NULL в последнем объекте, это должен быть указатель.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov метки `ооп`, `любой язык`. `Java` например.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov ну в терминах java сие поле (свойство) скорее не объект, а только ссылка на объект, то есть, можно сказать, указатель.

Comment: А, точно, у вас же там только указатели в Java.